# Binary Search Tree deletion procedure with children

Tags: data-structures, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

Wasn't sure how to word this question. Basically take the following BST:

```
       25
     /    \
   20      30
  /  \      / \
 18   23  27   31
/  \   /\
8  19 22 24
```

If I were to delete the value 25 and rotate the value 20 in its place, does it make more sense to append the 23 subtree to 27, or to append the 30 subtree to 24. And I don't mean specific to this case, but from a broader perspective.

Just to be clear, what is preferable between these two arrangements:

```
      20
    /    \
  18      23
 /  \      / \
8   19    22  24
                \
                 30
                /  \
              27   31

      20
    /    \
  18      30
 /  \     / \
8   19  27  31
        /
       23
      /  \
     22  24
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rotating 20 would not be the wisest decision. You should either replace it with the maximum value of the left sub-tree or the minimum value of the right sub-tree.

If you do wish to rotate the way you have, there is no difference between the heights of the tree's and both will be same in terms of time complexity.

Comment: That makes way more sense, and is simpler to implement, thanks!

Comment: Does this logic make sense:

1. Retrieve max value in left subtree (initially the root of the left subtree), along with the max values parent node (initially the root of the current subtree)

2. If the ultimate parent node is NOT the same as the original node, set the right subtree of that parent node to the left subtree of the node with the max value in the original nodes left subtree.

3. Duplicate the value and frequency/occurrence of the node with the max value in the original node's left subtree to the original node.